# how to select the one suggestion randomly among the five suggestions from google search box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

By using this code i can click one suggestion from all suggestions. I cannot click the suggestions randomly. I need to click one suggestion randomly and verify only the clicked the suggestion is displayed or not.

```
package google;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Google {
     public WebDriver driver;

     @Test(priority=1)
      public void Firefoxaccess() throws InterruptedException 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/naveenkumar.d/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");
          driver=new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
          driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("n");
          Thread.sleep(3000);
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]")).click();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compose a selector based on a `rand` method.

For example:
`r` = generate random number here

and the selector should be something like:

```
//ul[@role='listbox']/li[r]
```

As for how to check that the option was selected you need to check that the search `input` has your text.

Text should be `what you typed` concatenated with the text from your random option, meaning the text from `//ul[@role='listbox']/li[r]//b`

And the selector for the check: `//input[@name='q'][contains(@value, 'your_text')]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i don't know how to verify the element.